# Restrict static files access to authenticated users in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

we have an old asp.net web site (.Net 2.0), call it "ChildWeb" which has hundreds of pdf documents. Authentication for this website done by receiving a GUID from a parent website, call it "ParentWeb". Users will log in to the "ParentWeb" and then click on a link to navigate to the "ChildWeb".

In "ChildWeb" there is a condition check to check if there is a GUID or some values in Sessions to allow the user. If there is non then user will be redirected to log in page of "ParentWeb".

As this "ChildWeb" is not actually configured any authentication at the site level all the documents are exposed with out authentication if anybody know the URL for that document. I am looking for a way to fix this.

What I am thinking is to configure the application to use Forms Authentication and set the redirect URL to the "ParentWeb" (they are under same domain) and let the "ParentWeb" redirect to a page in "ChildWeb" which is configured to allow anonymous access and set the FormAuthentication cookie in that page based on same GUID or Session variable check. Then I can make the folder that contains all the documents is accessible to only authenticated users.

Are there any problems or risk with the above approach? Is there any other better approach by using Heep Handler or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to this.

First, an easy approach is to just create a download ashx handler. Pass in the GUID to authenticate and the PDF filename. This will mask where the PDF file is and, assuming your GUID expires, it will prevent them from using the same URL down the road.

If you are running on a dedicated server, another easy way to do this is just to move the PDF files outside your ASP.NET application folder. Create a directory on the root of your C: drive and copy the files there. Then create a generic .ashx handler. Pass in your GUID as a query parameter to the handler and in your handler, have it authenticate your GUID and serve up the appropriate PDF file. If you are using a shared hosting, you can also move the files to your App_Data folder which is automatically protected by ASP.NET.

Another approach, if feasible, is to encrypt all the PDF files and create a generic .ashx handler that, again, authenticates the GUID, decrypts the PDF file, then serves it up.

Yet another approach is to store the PDF files inside a SQL database. This approach is not recommended if your application has a lot of traffic. This will considerably slow down your application if there is a lot of traffic. But to do this, store the PDFs in SQL, then create an .ashx handler to authenticate the GUID and serve up the appropriate PDF file.

The final approach, of course, is as you suggested, to use Forms authentication. You can use the [location tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.71).aspx) to deny users access to your directory in your web.config.

Comment: Thank you Icemanind. Url's are hard coded in many places. So is it a good idea to write a HttpHandler that will check for the Session value (as I may not have GUID in every page) while service .pdf files. Or will it open up some security risk compared to writing download handler?

Comment: @user3731783 -- No, session will work. You can get the current session in the ashx handler using HttpContext.Current.Session.

Comment: Thank you. I think I am almost there. Works fine for unauthenticated users. For authenticated users as I am handling pdf files how can send the actual pdf to the browser?

Comment: Okay.. I got this working. I am writing the content back to response with WriteFile. Thanks a lot for your help.